# BeautifulSoup4: how to make find_all() return "N/A" when an item is absent on a page (python 3.6)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using `find_all()` to loop through many web pages and extract texts from targeted HTML elements. However, when the targeted `class` is absent , `find_all()` simply skips it without indicating the absence in any way, which ruins my data. For example, when I'm expecting 100 entries, `find_all()`  would return 95; but I need those missing 5 to be marked as something like 'N/A' rather than just omitted entirely from the output. What should I do?
I tried the following code and it didn't work, probably because the empty entries were never put into `author_list` in the first place since the targeted `div` or `class` was absent on certain pages. How can I get an explicit indication for the absence?

```
author_list = [] 
author_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field--name-field-citation-pages field--type-string field--label-hidden field__item'})
for author in author_list:
    if author in author_list:
        print(author.text)
    else: 
        print('N/A')
```

The output I want is something like ['x','x','x','x','x','x','N/A','x','x','N/A']; but want I am getting is ['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x']

Full Code:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas 

#make a list of all web pages' urls
webpages=[]
for i in range(15):
    root_url = 'https://cross-currents.berkeley.edu/archives?author=&title=&type=All&issue=All&region=All&page='+ str(i)
    webpages.append(root_url)
#start looping through all pages
titles = []
journals = []
authors = []
pages = []
dates = []
issues = []

for item in webpages:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    data = r.get(item, headers=headers)
    page_soup = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')

    #find targeted info and put them into a list to be exported to a csv file via pandas
    title_list = [title.text for title in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field-name-node-title'})]
    titles += [el.replace('\n', '') for el in title_list]

    journal_list = [journal.text for journal in page_soup.find_all('em')]
    journals += [el.replace('\n', '') for el in journal_list] 

    author_list = [author.text for author in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field--name-field-citation-authors field--type-string field--label-hidden field__item'})]
    authors += [el.replace('\n', '') for el in author_list]

    pages_list = [pages.text for pages in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field--name-field-citation-pages field--type-string field--label-hidden field__item'})]
    pages += [el.replace('\n', '') for el in pages_list]

    date_list = [date.text for date in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field--name-field-date field--type-datetime field--label-hidden field__item'})]
    dates += [el.replace('\n', '') for el in date_list]

    issue_list = [issue.text for issue in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class':'field field--name-field-issue-number field--type-integer field--label-hidden field__item'})]
    issues += [el.replace('\n', '') for el in issue_list]

dataset = {'Title': titles, 'Author': authors, 'Journal': journals, 'Date': dates, 'Issue': issues, 'Pages': pages}
```

Comment: Do you care which entry resulted in missing data? As in, do you need it to say entry 5 or entry 20 were missing data, or just 95 entries in total and the last 5 are N/A? (so that you have 100 entries total)

Comment: The former. I absolutely need the 'N/A' to be at the exact location in the list as it was found. The output I want is something like ['x','x','x','x','x','x','N/A','x','x','N/A']. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add enough code to allow us to run your test? i.e. URL

Comment: thanks i just added the full code  =)

Answer (score 0):

After getting all the 100 entries into the list, you are conducting a loop which basically loops through all the same 100 entries, which includues the "None" value also. That is why author is always present is author_list despite it gets null or the real output.

What you can do is, inside the loop check for any "None" or null value, and print not applicable for that each time.

Also, use findAll("div",{"class":"....."}) instead. It returns null value.

Comment: Thanks for the input! But how do I refer to a None value? Something like if author = 'None'?

Comment: if (author == None). 'None' refers to a string.

Comment: I tried this: for author in author_list:
        if author == None:
            print('N/A')
        else:
            print(author). I got the same result =(

Comment: 1. Have you written the condition inside parenthesis?
2. At first print the list with 100 authors. check what is the output when there is the targeted class is absent. Give condition according to that. 
3. Do your research in the parsed soup that when the author is absent what is the difference in soup? Give condition acc to that.

Comment: 4. Use try....except. If none of the above works. Print N/A when it handles exception

Comment: I did these and have found no evidence that the output of findAll or find_all contains a none value that can be targeted. =( Can you post a sample code that targets and proves the existence of the none value in the output of findAll?